# Include doxygen documentation in SVN repository

Tags: svn, doxygen

Is it good practice to include and commit the Doxygen HTML documentation for my project in the SVN repository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should generated documentation go into source control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983060/should-generated-documentation-go-into-source-control)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd tend to say **no** since the docs are generated stuff.

While there *might* be cases where this could be useful (e.g. when releasing a version that contains the docs) in general, generated content should be kept out of the VCS.

Versioning the docs would only make sense if you generate the docs freshly before each commit (which in my experience is usually not done). Otherwise, there might be the case that the generated documentation doesn't match the actual code.

Version the `doxyfile.dox` (where you store your generation settings) instead. If you distribute the settings, you could generate the documentation on-the-fly during installation of your project.